# Does GCM need to register everytime an app is opened?

Tags: android, cordova, firebase, phonegap-pushplugin

When my app registers with the push plugin, it disconnects firebase.  From that moment on it gets stuck in a loop of turning on when app is paused and off when app is resumed, so data is only ever loaded when app is not active.

The only solution I can think of is to register on first install and then reload the app.  But i'm not sure that GCM will work properly if I do not register every time the app is opened.

So I guess what I want to know is will GCM work if registering only after install?

Comment: no only when app version change and first time

Comment: Yes, it should work once registered. Why don't you just give it a try? And yes, what's the point of tagging firebase with this question anyway?

Comment: I tagged firebase because it is related to firebase in that only firebase loses connection on registering gcm.  So figured someone else using firebase would have experience with this.